# What role does the ideology Khomeinism play in modern day Iran?

Tags: iran, ideology, middle-east

I know that Khomeinism is the [founding ideology of the Islamic Republic of Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_thought_and_legacy_of_Ruhollah_Khomeini) based on the political ideology of  Grand Ayatollah Ruhollah Khomeini. What I want to know is how much influence does this ideology have on the modern people and politics of Iran, if any?

Comment: Doesn't the article you link to have a giant section on "legacy"? What else are you looking for?

Comment: I guess I am looking for more specific policies and rulings followed by modern Iran that are influenced by Khomeinism. While legacy is helpful, it doesn't really mention many specific policies created by or inspired by Khomeinism and their direct affects on the people of modern Iran. Some sections of legacy just give scholar options on Khomeinism, the beliefs of Khomeini and how they changed during the revolution, or how Khomeinism affected historical events in Iran - not modern Iran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A religious "supreme leader" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Leader_of_Iran
- Execution of gays. https://www.dw.com/en/iran-defends-execution-of-gay-people/a-49144899
- Ongoing terrorism  https://www.brookings.edu/blog/order-from-chaos/2019/01/24/the-iranian-revolution-and-its-legacy-of-terrorism/
- Incitement against the United States. https://www.reuters.com/article/us-iran-usa-embassy/iranians-chant-death-to-america-to-mark-u-s-embassy-seizure-idUSKBN1XE0KK
- Exporting the revolution  https://www.memri.org/reports/goals-second-phase-islamic-revolution-iran-next-40-years-%E2%80%93-part-three-irgc-commanders-speak